# Why isn't my current datetime in sync with the system clock all the time?

Tags: java, android, datetime

Although getting the instance of the current datetime works for when I launch my activity, if I go to another screen and click on the back button to go back to my previous activity, the datetime stays the same as when I first accessed the activity. Also if I keep my activity idle, the time does not update either. Is it because I am getting only an instance of the datetime? How can I prevent this?

Inside Activity:

```
long currentDateTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
Date date = new Date(currentDateTime);

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
String formatDate = format.format(date);

TextView currentDateTextView = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.current_datetime));
currentDateTextView.setText(formatDate);

SimpleDateFormat formatLong = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMMM d");
String formatDateLong = formatLong.format(date);

TextView currentDateLongTextView = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.current_datetime_long));
currentDateLongTextView.setText(formatDateLong);
```

EDIT:

Even though I put the above is in my onResume() method, I still have on problem:

If I remain on the screen, the time is static and does not update with my system time. What do I do in that event?

Comment: put that code in onResume method .

Comment: oh I will try. Right now, I only have it in onCreate()

Comment: onCreate doesnt get called when back button is used ( onBackPressed )

Comment: Thank you. I am testing it now :D

Comment: @TusharPandey, I have a problem where if I remain on the screen, the time is static and does not update with my system time. What do I do in that event?

Comment: That is because all of this information is loaded into memory once you enter your activity (if you put it in onResume). You need to do something to actually update it e.g. starting a worker thread or something that just keeps updating it in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `TextClock` instead

```
    <TextClock
    android:id="@+id/current_datetime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:format24Hour="HH:mm"
    android:format12Hour="HH:mm" />
```

and it works just fine! I didn't know about TextClock widget previously.